# Aizu Onlineジャッジの問題について(presentation error)

Tags: java

aizu onlineジャッジの[「長方形の描画」問題](http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/description.jsp?id=ITP1_5_A)を解いているのですが、presentation errorになってしまいます。
出力結果も大体あっていると思うのですが、どこが間違っているのでしょうか。
また、こうしたpresentation errorはどのように気をつければ防げるのでしょうか。

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{


    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            while(true){
                try{
            int H=scan.nextInt();
            int W=scan.nextInt();
            if(H==0&&W==0)break;

            for(int i=0;i<H;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<W;j++){
                    System.out.print('#');
                }System.out.print('\n');
              }System.out.println('\n');

                }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                    System.out.println("エラー:"+e);

                }

            }
            scan.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: 実際にやってみた訳で無いので未確認ですが、`System.out.println('\n');` で`println` を使っているので間の空行が２行になっています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

オンラインジャッジ系の判定において、一般的に presentation エラーとは、「結果はあっている様子だけれども、要求している output の仕様に違反している」を意味します。

一般的な対処方法としは、試しに実行したプログラムの出力結果を眺める・出力形式仕様を確認するなどして間違えないようにする（しかない）と思われます。