# 余分な空白などの、仕様に違反している箇所を見つけるには？

Tags: java

Aizu onlineの[「表計算」問題](http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/description.jsp?id=ITP1_7_C)を解いています。

下記のコードでは`presentation error`になってしまいます。
これは [Aizu Onlineジャッジの問題について(presentation error)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/24300/) によると、output の仕様に違反していることを意味しているようです。

しかし、一見`Sample Output`と同じ結果が得られています。
どこが違うのでしょうか。
また、こういった場合`Sample Output`との違いや、余分な空白などを見つけるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int r=scan.nextInt();
        int c=scan.nextInt();
        int[][] matrix_rc=new int[r+1][c+1];
        int sum_r;
        int[] sum_c=new int[c+1];
        Arrays.fill(sum_c, 0);
        for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
            sum_r=0;//毎回の行で初期化
            for(int j=0;j<c+1;j++){
                if(j!=c){
                matrix_rc[i][j]=scan.nextInt();
                sum_r+=matrix_rc[i][j];}
                else if(j==c){
                    matrix_rc[i][j]=sum_r;
                }//c+1列までを完成させた
                sum_c[j]+=matrix_rc[i][j];//j列をすべて足したものを配列に代入
            }
        }
        for(int j=0;j<c+1;j++){
            matrix_rc[r][j]=sum_c[j];
        }//r+1行の配列に代入
        for(int i=0;i<r+1;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<c+1;j++){
                System.out.print(matrix_rc[i][j]);
                if(j<=c){System.out.print(" ");}
            }System.out.println();
        }
        scan.close();
}


}
```

Comment: （確証なしですが）各行の列の最後の要素の後に空白があるのがいけないのでは？（空白は隣り合う整数に１つの空白を入れる）

Comment: 私が見る限り重複では無いです。再オープンに投票しておきます。デバッグの丸投げに見えるので、よい質問ではないと思いますが別の問題です。

Comment: 回答を記述するとしたら、おそらく自分は同じ回答を書いていただろうと思ったので、重複投票しました。

Comment: @YukiInoue  「間違えないようにする（しかない）」という回答は多くの質問の回答となり得るわけですが、全て重複にしてしまうのですか？  あの回答は良い回答だと思いますし、この質問にも「どこが間違っている」かは答えない方が本人のためかも知れません。しかし、ここは何が教育上望ましいか考える場所ではないと思います。例えば宿題の丸投げであっても、質問として成り立っているなら、放って置くしかないのでは？

Comment: @mjy うーん、これについて少し考えてみたのですが、多分この問題の背景(根本)にある問題は、やっぱり「 presentation error にどう取り組んでいくのがよいか」なのだと思います。それについて回答をしようとした観点でこの問題を眺めてみると、やっぱり同じ問題が聞かれているように見えてくるので、その意味で重複なのではないのか、と思っています。

Comment: わかりました。少し具体性を高める形で編集してみました。重複候補とは見た目で違いが分からない状況、という点で異なった質問になったと思います。これでも「間違えないようにする（しかない）」という意味では同じ回答があり得るとは思いますが、皆さまご検討下さい。

Answer (score 2):

サンプルのInputとOutputがありますので、それを利用して入出力の仕様に沿った出力になっているか確認するプログラムを書けば良いように思います。

```
public class TestTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // 入力仕様
        String[] input = new String[]{
                "4 5",
                "1 1 3 4 5",
                "2 2 2 4 5",
                "3 3 0 1 1",
                "2 3 4 4 6",
        };

        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(String.join(System.lineSeparator(), input).getBytes()));

        // 出力結果を保持
        PrintStream originalOut = System.out;
        ByteArrayOutputStream dummyOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(dummyOut));

        // 実行
        test.main(null);

        // 出力仕様
        String[] expect = new String[]{
                "1 1 3 4 5 14",
                "2 2 2 4 5 15",
                "3 3 0 1 1 8",
                "2 3 4 4 6 19",
                "8 9 9 13 17 56"
        };

        System.setOut(originalOut);

        String[] actual = dummyOut.toString().split(System.lineSeparator());
        if(expect.length != actual.length) {
            throw new RuntimeException("出力される行数が違います。\n"
                    + "期待行数\t["+expect.length+"]\n"
                    + "結果行数\t["+actual.length+"]");
        }

        for(int i = 0, length = actual.length; i < length; i++) {
            if(!expect[i].equals(actual[i])) {
                throw new RuntimeException("結果に差異があります。\n"
                        + "期待値\t["+expect[i]+"] \n"
                        + "結果\t["+actual[i]+"]");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("おめでとー");
    }
}
```

質問にある`test`クラスでテストをすると、結果は以下のようになります。

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 結果に差異があります。
期待値 [1 1 3 4 5 14] 
結果   [1 1 3 4 5 14 ]
    at TestTest.main(TestTest.java:48)
```

「末尾に空白があるため、期待結果と異なる」ということを機械的に検出できます。